# How to handle existing double value with Jquery Mask Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am using a Jquery mask plugin to format a double value in a textbox. I am using the following plugin.

https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Thats my code:

```
$document.ready(){ 
$('.money').mask("#,##0", {reverse: true});
}
```

It is working fine while typing in a value e.g. 1000 is set to 1.000
But after leaving the textbox, the value is parsed into double so it will set to: 1000.0 (in background)

After I get back to the site with the textbox the Jquery is masking again but with of course the double value, so its getting into: 100.000

Has anyone got an idea how I can handle this? I want to display the value without decimals and also with the right 1000-separator.

Comment: You can't just handle the value in the background and cast it to int?